onClick event not being called on span inside of a Canvas
I have a following code:


.playerDraft_cListOfPlayers {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.playerDraft_ListOfPlayers {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.playerDraft_ListOfPlayers span {
    display:inline-block;
}
#gameFieldDraftPlayersPitch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1615px;
}
<div class="playerDraft_cListOfPlayers">
    <canvas id="gameFieldDraftPlayersPitch"></canvas>
    <div class="playerDraft_ListOfPlayers">
        <span onclick="alert('Test 1');">Player 1</span>
        <span onclick="alert('Test 2');">Player 2</span>
        <span onclick="alert('Test 3');">Player 3</span>
    </div>
</div>



and that onclick event (which should call alert('Test 1, 2, 3..'); is not being called.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Add a background color for #gameFieldDraftPlayersPitch, and you will easily see that your canvas is on top of those links, on the z-axis. Either place it below them, or make the canvas element itself ignore any pointer events using pointer-events: none. (The latter would of course only make sense, if you don't need to interact with the canvas itself using the mouse/pointing device.)

The issue occurs because the <canvas> element is blocking the click events on the spans underneath it. To fix this:
Option 1: Add pointer-events: none; to the canvas's CSS to allow clicks to pass through to the spans.
#gameFieldDraftPlayersPitch {
    pointer-events: none;
}

Option 2: Increase the z-index of the spans to position them above the canvas.
.playerDraft_ListOfPlayers span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

Choose the option that best fits your use case.
